# 503 error when trying to upload image file on deployed react client & express server, followed by CORS error

Tags: reactjs, express, heroku, multer, http-status-code-503

I am trying to make a POST request which contains in request body json and also a file. To do that I'm using multer in my express server and the cors is enabled ( app.use(cors()). Unfortunately this POST request doesn't work in **deployed** app and i get this CORS error:
`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://....server.herokuapp...' from origin 'https://...client...herokuapp...' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

I have tried everything but didn't worked for me...
When I enable cors from chrome extension ([cors chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf/related)), I get 503 server error.

This is my server.ts file:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrVxG.png)

POST method:
`routerExample.post("/create", upload.single('file'), async (req, res) => { const { file, body: { name, hostEmail, hostPhoneNumber, about, location } } = req; ......;`

**FYI:** I do not have any problem with that on local development

Answer (score 0):

Your cors config doesn't send "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" in header response (**credentials: true**) and not authorize access from external origins IPs ( **origin: "*"**). To achieve those, try to change cors config to:

```
app.use(
  cors({
    credentials: true,
    origin: "*",
  })
);
```

If it works, don't forget to change "*" to authorized IP or domain client that access this server.

Comment: Also I think there could be another problem. On local development I save my images in src/images. if (file) {
            fileName = name + Math.random() + '.jpg';
            await pipeline(file.stream, fs.createWriteStream(`${__dirname}/../images/${fileName}`));
        }

Comment: And I use express static to reach this folder in my react app (img src={`${baseUrl}/static/imagename`}). server ts: app.use('/static', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'images'))); I think after the build & deploy the server will not be able to find my images folder because it does not exists in my build folder. I do not know how to solve that...

Answer (score 0):

I solved it! Tha main problem was with image saving on server side. I saved the image in src/images and when I deployed the app, my route did not find the path where the image was. So I had to create a public folder inside my server project dir and store images here.